# Orwhere has method does not allow null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFvGe.png)I am trying to implement a many to many relationship search with 2 models. 
i get input from multiple checkbox values and want to search for items that match A or B when there is an input of data.

I read this url and wrote the same logic.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/many-to-many-relationship-with-2-pivot-table-data-search

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
    $languages = $request->lang;
    $fields = $request->field;

    $agencies = Agency::with('languages')->with('specialized_fields')
        ->orWhereHas('languages', function($query) use ($languages) {
            $query->whereIn('language_id', $languages);
        })
        ->orWhereHas('specialized_fields', function($query) use ($fields) {
            $query->whereIn('specialized_field_id', $fields);
        })
        ->get();

        dd($agencies);
}
```

i expected to achieve A or B search but instead I got this error.

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/jtf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 907

it seems that it causes this error if either A or B is null, but why??? Does the OrWhereHas method work only when theres an input??

/added info/

my error message 
my agency model

> class Agency extends Model {
>       protected $guarded = [
>           'id'
>       ];
>
> ```
> public function languages(){
>     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Language');
> }
> public function specialized_fields(){
>     return $this->belongsToMany('App\SpecializedField');
> }
>
> public function region(){
>     return $this->hasOne('App\Region');
> } }
> ```

Comment: By the way, you're keep asking, but you don't take care the answers, not accepting the correct one. That's not how stackoverflow works. Thanks.

Comment: ohhh okay thanks for pointing it out
i just signed up and didnt know
i'll be careful next time

Comment: if there are questions I can answer as a noob, I will, if that's what you mean. Sorry English is not my native language.

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. I mean, if you're questioning, then take care the question. If someone is commenting or answering your question, you need to respond at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because either `$languages` or `$fields` is `null`.

Since `->whereIn()` is expecting an array, but you're passing null.

You just need to make sure you're passing an array.

```php
$languages = array_filter((array) $request->lang); // cast to array & remove null value
$fields = array_filter((array) $request->field);

$agencies = Agency::with('languages', 'specialized_fields')
    ->orWhereHas('languages', function($query) use ($languages) {
        $query->whereIn('language_id', $languages);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('specialized_fields', function($query) use ($fields) {
        $query->whereIn('specialized_field_id', $fields);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm speculating that you started your where query chain with an `orWhereHas()` which may have caused the problem, try starting with `whereHas()` instead.

```
 public function search(Request $request){
     $languages = $request->lang;
     $fields = $request->field;

     $agencies = Agency::with('languages', 'specialized_fields') // you can get away by just using one with(), not needed but its cleaner this way
         ->whereHas('languages', function($query) use ($languages) { // previously orwherehas
                 $query->whereIn('language_id', $languages);
         }) ->orWhereHas('specialized_fields', function($query) use ($fields) {
             $query->whereIn('specialized_field_id', $fields);
         })
         ->get();

     dd($agencies);
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your correction! but I still got the same error.

Comment: what laravel version are you running? can i see your `Agency` model? the arguments for `with()` and `whereHas()` should be the function name for your relations.

Comment: version:   "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
and I edited my post and added my agency model.

Comment: `whereHas()` is probably not the problem upon checking, `whereIn` is the problem. Try `dd()`ing `$languages` and `$fields` make sure they are an array.